# Simple Java power recursion

Tags: java, recursion, int, long-integer

So the recursive function I'm making takes 2 variables (`x` and `y`) and calculates `x` to the power of `y`. Just like the `Math.pow` function. `y` is positive, so I don't need to worry about negative exponents.
This is my code:

```
public static int power(int x, int y) {     
    if (y == 0)         
        return 1;           
    else        
        return x * power(x, y-1);
}
```

At first it seemed like it worked fine, but then I tried to enter `power(50,6)`. I got `-1554869184`.
Obviously this is wrong because the correct answer can't be negative.

Comment: Try using _public long power(int x, int y)_ instead

Comment: What is the largest possible integer value? What is the value of 50^6? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Comment: Use Long instead of int. int can't store such large reuslt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004944/max-value-of-integer

Comment: Thanks I understand it now. I'm sorry I'm new to all of this. I feel so dumb now :)

Comment: @niana Because an **ant** can't eat **elephant** :-)

Comment: @Nabin Haha right :)

Comment: why are you using recursion for such a trivial task? Is this some kind of homework?

Comment: Kind of. It's a recursion exercise I found on the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is good, but it doesn't work for numbers that are too long.

`int` has 4-bytes (32 bits) => the maximum value is `2147483647` ( `2^31-1` ), total: `2^32` values (there are also some negative numbers)

`long` has 8-bytes (64 bits) => the maximum value is `9223372036854775807` ( `2^63-1` ), total: `2^64` values

Those values can be found in Java using:

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE     // Integer and int have the same range
Long.MAX_VALUE        // Long and long have also the same range
```

For your case:
`50^6 = 15625000000` is a valid `long` number, but not a valid `int` (it's bigger than `2^32-1` )

**Be careful:**

If you try to use numbers that are longer you can have problems with `long`, too.
E.g.:

```
power(10,18);  // OK
power(10,19);  // not OK: negative number
power(10,20);  // not OK: even if the number is positive
               //         the answer is not good - it has only 18 digits!
```