# Can't count the number above 3 billion

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I've got a problem here, when I calculate a figure of more than 2 billion and 3 billion are always error and displays the force close. So what I need to fix it

```
long  initial_investment, total_investment;
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat ("###,###,###,###");
initial_investment = Integer.parseInt( Text1.getText().toString());


if (initial_investment <= 1000000000)
                 {

                     total_investment = ((initial_investment * 3) /100)+ total_investment;
                     Text5.setText(df.format(total_investment));

                 }
                 else if (initial_investment > 1000000000 && initial_investment <= 3000000000L )
                 {

                     total_investment = (long) (((initial_investment* 2.5) /100)+ total_investment);
                     Text5.setText(df.format(total_investment));

                 }
                 else if (initial_investment > 3000000000L )
                        {

                        total_investment = ((initial_investment * 2) /100)+ total_investment;
                        Text5.setText(df.format(total_investment));

                        }

            }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004944/max-value-of-integer

Comment: Is `initial_investment` an integer? Integers can't go above 2.14 billion.

Comment: the example doesn't show whether the initial_investment is an integer or long...

Comment: @matthew  the initial investment is an long

Comment: How about `total_investment`? What is `df`, DecimalFormat?

Comment: yes, to spruce digits

Comment: total_investment also use long

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use [`BigInteger`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigInteger.html) if you are dealing with some very large value. You can use it as shown below

```
BigInteger bi1, bi2, bi3;  

// assign values to bi1, bi2
bi1 = new BigInteger("123");
bi2 = new BigInteger("50");

// perform add operation on bi1 using bi2
bi3 = bi1.add(bi2);

String str = "Result of addition is " +bi3;
```

Comment: what is the meaning of the quotation marks "123" and "50" ?

Comment: @RickyAN BigInteger takes the number in as a string

Comment: @intboolstring The method parseInt(String) is undifined for the type BigInteger

Comment: why do you need a `parseInt` type of method when constructor itself can convert `String` to `BigInteger`?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
initial_investment= Long.parseLong( Text1.getText().toString());
```

instead of

```
initial_investment = Integer.parseInt( Text1.getText().toString());
```

Comment: If this helped you, you could accept it as the correct answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is my fault, but now I've had to fix it I just need to change initial_investment from int to an long

```
initial_investment = Long.parseLong( Text1.getText().toString());
```