# Input from file refuses to become an int/or be read as an int

Tags: java

Solved: The problem was that the integer's values were too high and thus could not be stored in a int, but rather had to be stored in a BigInteger.

This code is intended to read input from a file(shown below) and I would like it to be read as an int or parsed to an int as I need to be able to apply math to it. It always throws the exception, "InputMismatchException".
I have read many other questions and their solutions and still to implement their solutions with little to no success. The solutions include parsing the string as an int, removing whitespace with  "ReplaceAll".

Code:

```
String fileName = "SBOWorkSpace.txt";
Scanner sf = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

int lineint = sf.nextInt();
int finalnumbers = lineint * hour;
System.out.println(finalnumbers + hournum);

String linestring = sf.nextLine();
String nospaces = linestring.replaceAll("\\s+\\u00A0]+$", "");
int filetonumbers = Integer.parseInt(nospaces);
```

File:

```
46886794368454912286794394376459086711
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "46886794368454912286794394376459086711"
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2097)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050)
at Encryption.main(Encryption.java:881)
```

Comment: You want this as a single number ?

Comment: First of all: this digit ist way too big for an `int`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004944/max-value-of-integer). Then: print the value of `nospaces`. What do you get?

Comment: @AbhishekPanjabi Yes, I would like the number to be able to be stored in a single variable

Comment: Try doing double filetonumbers = Double.parseDouble(nospaces)

Comment: @pzaenger Is there any way to get around the int's limitation?

Comment: Yup. You can use type double.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful I copied and pasted the number directly in from the file, so it does appear to just be a single number

Comment: @AbhishekPanjabi Ok thank you, I will be trying use the long double and double and I will update with the results.

Comment: Double will hold ur results as it has capacity of storing 308 digits .

Comment: @AbhishekPanjabi but sometimes the value stored in the file will be higher, than 308 digits, will long double handle this?

Comment: When you store a number as a Double, only the first 16 or 17 digits are stored exactly the way you specified them. Double is basically scientific notation, but with powers of 2 instead of powers of 10.

Comment: @DavidK perfect timing, I was just trying to figure out how to remove it from the scientific notation thing

Answer (score 3):

The [Java class `Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) has a maximum value,
2^31 - 1, which is the 10-digit number 2147483647.
The number you are trying to put in an Integer has 38 decimal digits,
so it is much larger than the largest number an Integer can hold
and Java will not let you put it in an Integer.

You might want to try working with [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) instead.
For example,

```
BigInteger filetonumbers = new BigInteger(nospaces);
```

If you [search SO for "biginteger" and "java",](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/biginteger+java)
you will find a lot of questions and answers; some of these are
irrelevant to you, but some others discuss
java.math.BigInteger and show some examples of the
class being used in non-trivial ways.

Comment: Thank you, could you possibly give me an example of how to use BigInteger, I read through the link you provided and am still unsure of how to use it.

Comment: You won't be able to convert it to a primitive like with `parseInt`; you'd have to actually store all your numbers (at least any big ones) in `BigInteger` objects and learn the functions that allow you to do math operations with them (for example, you can't use `+` to add two BigIntegers, but you can use the `add` function). I added another starting link to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The length of a int is from`- 2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647`
 and you are assigning large value that is beyond int capacity
it is also large from the capacity of long datatype

Answer (score 0):

```
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2097)
```

Maybe the scanner can't parse your int cause it's too large to be an int ?

[Maximum value of an int32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94591/what-is-the-maximum-value-for-a-int32)