# Getting number format exception

Tags: java

I am doing simple conversion from string to int but getting number format exception :

I have use below java Program :

```
String cId = "7000000141";
int iCid = Integer.parseInt(cId);
System.out.println(iCid);
```

Getting below exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "7000000141"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:459)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:497)
```

Why I am getting the above exception?

Comment: It's out of range.

Comment: The maximum value of an int is around 2 billion. 7 billion is too big.

Comment: Its because of value is more than integer range int:   32 bit
for integer the value range starts  from -2147483648 to 2147483647

Answer (score 1):

That's because it's out of range of integer. The maximum allowed value for `integer` is `2147483647`

**In Java**, following are the minimum and maximum values.

```
        width                     minimum                         maximum
int:   32 bit              -2 147 483 648                  +2 147 483 647
long:  64 bit  -9 223 372 036 854 775 808      +9 223 372 036 854 775 807
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15005226/2815219)

---

Use a 'long' datatype instead

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String cId = "7000000141";
    long iCid = Long.parseLong(cId);
    System.out.println(iCid);
  }
}
```