# I cannot insert 10 digit number as input in int or string variable in android.it says an error "integer is too long"

Tags: android

In my case in need give 10 mobile number as input to start a phone intent

Here is my code

```
    public void dialPhone(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Please help me .I am just a beginner so please give me somewhat detailed answer

Comment: Why would you ever want to use a **numeric** type? A **string** will do, in this case. Unless you don't want to do **math** with a phone number. In which case, a **long** would do the trick (the max value for an int is 2^31 - 1).

Comment: I had tried "long" and "Biginteger".Still getting the same error " integer value is too long

Comment: Maybe you didn't try the most logical thing: **string**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error `integer is too long` error because in Java, the `int` data type specifies a **32 bit integer**, and thus is limited to the minimum and maximum values of `-2 147 483 648` and `+2 147 483 647` respectively. (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15005226/6346531) for more details)

Your phone number most likely exceeds this range of `int` data type. For this particular problem, you can (and probably should) use the `String` class for `phoneNumber`, as that is what the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#parse(java.lang.String)) specifies:

`Uri parse (String uriString)`

Thus, modify your code to make `phoneNumber` a `String` object, and it should work without any errors.

Comment: Thanks it work with string.I had tried string before, but I had forgotten to put quotation mark.