# How come java longs MAX_VALUE < java floats MAX_VALUE despite being 64bit vs 32bit

Tags: java

Like the title says, I don't understand how Java's primitive data type `long` maximum and minimum values are smaller than a `float`'s maximum and minimum. Despite the `long` being 64bit and `float` being 32bit.

What is going on?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004944/max-value-of-integer). It is not a direct answer, but it contains the exact explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the reason is because a float using floating point precision.  A Long can store a high number of precise digits, while I float can store a high value but without the same precision in its lower bits.

In a sense, a float stores values in scientific/exponential notation.  thus a large value can be stored in a small number of bits.  Think 2 x10^200, this is huge number but can be stored in a small number of bits.

Answer (score 4):

A 32-bit `float` isn't just a simple number, like a `long`; it's broken up into fields.  The fields are:

- 1 bit for the sign;
- 8 bits for the exponent, which is a power of 2;
- 23 bits for the mantissa.

The exponent field is encoded (usually, it's just an offset from the real exponent), but it represents exponents from -126 to 127.  (That covers 254 of the possible 256 values; the other two are used for special purposes.)  The mantissa represents a value that can be from 1 to a value just below 2 (actually 2 - 2<sup>-23</sup>).  This means that the largest possible `float` is 2<sup>127</sup> x (2 - 2<sup>-23</sup>), or almost 2<sup>128</sup>, which is larger than the largest possible `long` value which is 2<sup>63</sup>-1.

More information:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

http://www.adambeneschan.com/How-Does-Floating-Point-Work/showfloat.php?floatvalue=340282346638528859811704183484516925440&floattype=float