# How to add integer and Varchar(20) and store as Varchar(20) in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, user-interface, jframe

I have db named spareparts in which all values are stored as varchar(20).
I am taking input from the user through jtextfield as a number then convert into integer.
s1(which is itemcode) and s2(which is quantity to be added to actual quantity) are the input Now I want to add this input into 'quantity'(which is also varchar) as:

```
public class AddStockDAO{
   Connection connection;
   PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
   ResultSet resultSet;
   Statement statement;

   public AddStockDAO(String s1,String s2)
   {
       int num=Integer.parseInt(s2);
       String sql= "select "+
             " cast(quantity as INT) from spareparts"+
             "set quantity+= "+num+
             " cast(quantity as varchar(20))"+
             "where itemcode='?'";
       try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", "root", "")) {
           try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
               stmt.setString(1, s1);

               stmt.executeUpdate();
           }
       } catch (SQLException ex) {   
           Logger.getLogger(AddProductGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }

   } 
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify? You want to save that number into "NUM_EnteredByUser" or you want to get that number from DB select? What is the code example for?

Comment: I believe op is trying to take two values from a user: the number to add to quantity and the itemcode.

Comment: User will enter some number is jtextfield, which I will get from this class's constructor. The s1 is the itemcode entered by the user and the s2 is the quantity entered by the user. I want to add this quantity into original database where id is the id which user entered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want to update the record in the DB according to the itemcode. So you just cast the existing value to number, add your additional value (with `+`) and cast it back.

```
int num = 0;
try {
    num = Integer.parseInt(s2);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println('Nope, that was not a number');
    //Do something else?
}
String insertQuery = "UPDATE spareparts SET quantity = cast(cast(quantity as integer)+"+num+" as char(20)) where itemcode = "+s1+";";

try {
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(...); //add your data
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
} catch (Exception e) {
    //Something broke
}
```

Also - You should use the class variables you've defined at the top of your class, so you don't have to recreate the connection later on. 
But If you add more `AddStockDAO`, each of them will create new connection, so I'd suggest you create a database class where you setup a connection and just pass some data or a query to a method to run it on the existing connection.

Comment: This query is just updating value I want this query to add value into already existing value

Comment: Oh, so if there is a value of 3, and person put 4, you want to update to 7?

Comment: I mean if the value of quantity is 15 and user enters 10 it should save it as quantity=25

Comment: @SYEDSHEHROZSOHAIL - see my changed `insertQuery`

Comment: @SYEDSHEHROZSOHAIL accept this as the correct answer please

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend this. How would you know if an Integer + Varchar(20) is more than 20 characters?

Comment: It can't be. See [max value of integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004944/max-value-of-integer)

Comment: @Matt I know that in Java there is a max value for integer, but the number in the DB is a varchar(20). I would recommend using a BigInteger for the addition.

Comment: I just want to add small values, actually it is a database which will contain quantity of products which can be in thousands at max

Comment: User will enter some number in jtextfield, which I will get from this class's constructor. The s1 is the itemcode entered by the user and the s2 is the quantity entered by the user. I want to add this quantity into original database where id is the id which user entered

Answer (score 0):

As @Connor has said, there is no way to make sure the result is less than 20 characters, so using a BigInteger field is much better, but if the field MUST be a varchar(20), I would recommend selecting that field from the database, doing the addition in java, and then storing the result back in the database.