# How do I validate an integer field in a Request bean, if the entered value is greater than the range of an int?

Tags: java, bean-validation

To validate a Integer field in Request bean, I used `@range (min=0,max=99999999,message="invalid") and @digits().` they are throwing the error

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Numeric value (1111118493411) out of range of int;
```

1. My need is to validate a Integer field and throw validation error in the request layer itself.
2. my db has a field with size 10 which of type int4.
3. I don't want user to pass value greater than 10digits.

How do I handle this in my request layer itself to restrict the user from entering more than 10 digits

```
@JsonProperty(value = "qty", required = true)
@NotNull
@Range(min=0, max=999999999 , message = "invalid")
private Integer qty;
```

I wish to throw an error stating invalid if the user enters more than 10 digits.

Comment: This is going to be a problem at some point no matter what; you might as well let the parse error bubble up. Otherwise, you could use a `Long` in your DTO.

Comment: Even long also have a limited range maximum- '9,223,372,036,854,775,807' . If OP wants to control the validation message, better do it as BigInteger or String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Max **int** value is  `2,147,483,647` in java. You can see in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004944/max-value-of-integer/15005226#15005226). Your value is bigger than **max int** value. So you should change qty's class field type(example long).