# Why is the sum of even position of fibonacci series giving aswer as negative answer?

Tags: java, arrays, sum, runtime-error, fibonacci

constraint-in java, should use array, sum should be calculated when position is even and a[i]

```
import java.util.*;
class abc
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int sum=0;
      int n=sc.nextInt();
      int a[]=new int[n];
      a[0]=1;
      a[1]=2;
      for(int i=2;i<n;i++)
      {
        a[i]=a[i-1]+a[i-2];
        if(a[i]<n && i%2==0)
        sum=sum+a[i];
      }
      System.out.println(sum);
  }
}
```

input-
50
output-
-298632831

Comment: Looks like you are overflowing the `int` type.

Answer (score 1):

In java `int` is **4 bytes** long which has range of **-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483, 647**. So in your case `int` `sum` is overflowing. Because when n = 50 febonacci series gives result as **12586269025**. Which is beyond the limit of `int`.

So you should rather use a `long` to hold the `sum`. Which is **8 bytes** with limit of **-9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807**.

Even you need to use long array, because you are performing operations after assigning values to array elements. So updated code should be:

```
long sum = 0;
    final long a[] = new long[50];
    a[0] = 1L;
    a[1] = 2L;
    final int n = 50;
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
      a[i] = a[i - 1] + a[i - 2];
      if (a[i] < n && i % 2 == 0) {
        sum = sum + a[i];
      }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```

Note (as suggested by Mihir): `long` is also having limitations, so till **n = 92**, it will work fine. If you can have n > 92 you need to use `BigInteger`. Which is also having further limits. So consider these limitations in your code.

> BigInteger must support values in the range -2Integer.MAX_VALUE
>   (exclusive) to +2Integer.MAX_VALUE (exclusive) and may support values
>   outside of that range.
>
> Implementation note: BigInteger constructors and operations throw
>   ArithmeticException when the result is out of the supported range of
>   -2Integer.MAX_VALUE (exclusive) to +2Integer.MAX_VALUE (exclusive).

Comment: I'd suggest recommending something like `BigInteger` over `long` because `long` will also overflow at around the 92nd fibonacci number.

Comment: I've used an if condition in which I will calculate sum only if a[i] is even and it's less than n. if I enter 50, it should only sum 2 8 34 right ? why does my if condition not seem to work, it would really be helpful if you explain this bit.

Comment: It is sum of 3, 8, 21 corresponding to position 2, 4 and 6.

Answer (score 1):

Fib(50) = 12_586_269_025 (see [here](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibtable.html) for example)

Java, max int: 2_147_483_647 (go [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004944/max-value-of-integer))

Short story short: use the long type, and of course:

- learn to make a good guess about the "size" of your results
- then learn about the constraints that types have, like their max value

In other words, the real answer is: there are limits to everything in computing. It is really crucial to understand them.

Comment: I've used an if condition in which I will calculate sum only if a[i] is even and it's less than n. if I enter 50, it should only sum 2 8 34 right ?

Comment: My question was not just fibonacci, it was sum of even position of fibonacci series, it was a question given to me with the constraints I had mentioned. I was told to use array. I'm still unable to understand the reason behind why the if condition seems to be 'not working'. Thanks for the help though. Also @GhostCat , I didn't respond in the initial days of asking question because someone in my family passed away and I wasn't using internet then. Thought you were being rude, but then I read your bio so it's fine.

Comment: I am sorry I hear that. I did not mean to be rude. It is just a too common pattern: people leave dubious content, and then walk away. When that happened to you 10, 20, 50 times you probably sometimes lose your temper. Sorry for that, and all the best wishes.