# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal sequence boundaries Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using Azure Databricks and Scala. I wanna show() a Dataframe but I obtained an error that I can not understand and I would like to solve it. The lines of code that I have are:

```
println("----------------------------------------------------------------Printing schema")
df.printSchema()
println("----------------------------------------------------------------Printing dataframe")
df.show()
println("----------------------------------------------------------------Error before")
```

The Standard output is the following one, the message "----------------------------------------------------------------Error before" it does not appears.

```
>     ----------------------------------------------------------------Printing schema
>     root
>      |-- processed: integer (nullable = false)
>      |-- processDatetime: string (nullable = false)
>      |-- executionDatetime: string (nullable = false)
>      |-- executionSource: string (nullable = false)
>      |-- executionAppName: string (nullable = false)
>     
>     ----------------------------------------------------------------Printing dataframe
>     2020-02-18T14:19:00.069+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1497248K->191833K(1789440K)] 2023293K->717886K(6063104K),
> 0.0823288 secs] [Times: user=0.18 sys=0.02, real=0.09 secs] 
>     2020-02-18T14:19:40.823+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1637209K->195574K(1640960K)] 2163262K->721635K(5914624K),
> 0.0483384 secs] [Times: user=0.17 sys=0.00, real=0.05 secs] 
>     2020-02-18T14:19:44.843+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1640950K->139092K(1809920K)] 2167011K->665161K(6083584K),
> 0.0301711 secs] [Times: user=0.11 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
>     2020-02-18T14:19:50.910+0000: Track exception: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 59 in stage 62.0 failed 4 times, most recent
> failure: Lost task 59.3 in stage 62.0 (TID 2672, 10.139.64.6, executor
> 1): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal sequence boundaries:
> 1581897600000000 to 1581811200000000 by 86400000000
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage23.processNext(Unknown
> Source)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$15$$anon$2.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:659)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
>       at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:139)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:112)
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:497)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1526)
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:503)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>     
>     Driver stacktrace:.
>     2020-02-18T14:19:50.925+0000: Track message: Process finished with exit code 1. Metric: Writer. Value: 1.0.
```

Comment: It may help if you can show us how yo reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well the first step to solve any problem is to be able to minimise it and make it reproducible.

Answer (score 8):

It's hard to know exactly without seeing your code, but I had a similar error and [the other answer (about `int` being out of range)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60283423/1661212) led me astray.

The `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` you are getting is confusing but is actually quite specific:

```
Illegal sequence boundaries: 1581897600000000 to 1581811200000000 by 86400000000
```

This error is complaining that that you are using a `sequence()` spark SQL function and you are telling it to go *from* 1581897600000000 *to* 1581811200000000 *by* 86400000000. It's easy to miss because of the big numbers, but this an instruction to go *from* a larger number *to* a smaller number *by* an increment of a positive integer. E.g., *from* 12 *to* 6 *by* 3.

This is **not allowed** according to [the DataBricks documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/functions.html#sequence):

> - start - an expression. The start of the range.
> - stop - an expression. The end the range (inclusive).
> - step - an optional expression. The step of the
>     range. By default step is 1 if start is less than
>     or equal to stop, otherwise -1. For the temporal 
>     sequences it’s 1 day and -1 day respectively. **If 
>     start is greater than stop then the step must be 
>     negative, and vice versa.**

Additionally, I believe the other answer's focus on the `int` column is misleading. The large numbers mentioned in the illegal sequence error look like they are coming from a date column. You don't have any DateType columns but your string columns are named like date columns; presumably you are using them in a sequence function and they are getting coerced into dates.

Answer (score 4):

You can get this error when you attempt to

```
sequence(start_date, end_date, [interval])
```

on a table which has some of start_dates less than end_dates and others greater

When applying this function all of date ranges should be either positive or negative, not mixed

Answer (score 0):

Your schema is expecting an int, an [int in Java has a maximum size of [-2 147 483 648 to           +2 147 483 647]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004944/max-value-of-integer).

So I would change the schema from int to long.

Comment: How do you know is that error? Do you know how can I know which column is giving me that issue? Will you change the schema like that "spark.sql("SELECT (column_int as long)"

Comment: You only have a single column with `int`, named `processed`. However I am not sure how the int is generated or where it came from. It is a guess, based on the available inputs.