# to_string().length() giving incorrect results in c++. Can anyone please explain me this behavior?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,t;
    cin>>n;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>t;
        cout<<to_string(t).length();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Test Cases:
Input-123  //Correct
Output-3

Intput-111111111111111111111111         //Incorrect
Output-10

Input-11111  //Incorrect
Output-1010

Comment: 111111111111111111111111  probably won't fit in an integer. Try printing t after the cin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [max value of integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004944/max-value-of-integer)

Comment: @S.M. the third one will fit tho

Comment: Check the returned value of `(cin>>t)` or `cin.fail()`. After the second input `cin` is failed and does not perform read, so `t` is not changed and has old length 10. You get double output of 10: 1010.

Comment: Just use a 78-bit integer, and it'll work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely caused by cin reading as much of an int as it can when you assign 111111111111111111111111 to t, note that 111111111111111111111111 goes beyond the capacity size for int, it even goes beyond the capacity of long long int. Then as for fixing your output, chain an endl statement to the end of your output statement as so:

`cout << to_string(t).length() << endl;`

If you insist on making your code work for integers that exceed capacity then you might want to check out some arithmetic libraries such as the
[GMP Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org/)