# How do set the max value in variable by(int) in java?

Tags: java

if I want to set the max value for the variable and its from (double) we say: double.MAX_VALUE;
but how can I do that with a variable from ( int )
I hope you understand what I mean;

Comment: Guess what: `Integer.MAX_VALUE` exists as well.

Comment: thank you very very much, I thought:( int.MAX_VALUE ); what a stupid mistake ‍♂️

Comment: Does this answer your question? [max value of integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004944/max-value-of-integer)

Answer (score 1):

The property you're looking for is [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE), which holds the maximum value a java `int` can have, that is 2<sup>31</sup> - 1.

Comment: I couldn't find a duplicate. If someone does find one, please let me know. I'll happily delete this.