# Why I am getting -2147483648 and -1's multiplication, negative i.e. -2147483648, instead it should be +2147483648

Tags: java, integer

This is the code snippet I had written for [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/divide-two-integers/) question in Leetcode.

```
 public static int quotient(int dividend,int divisor){
        int n=Math.abs(divisor),count=0,ans=Integer.MAX_VALUE-1;
        if(Math.abs(dividend)==1 && Math.abs(divisor)==1){
            return dividend*divisor;
        }
        else if(Math.abs(divisor)==1){
            if(dividend<0 && divisor<0)
                return Math.abs(dividend);
            return dividend*divisor;
        }
        else if(dividend==0){
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            while (true) {
                if (n > Math.abs(dividend)) {
                    ans = count;
                    break;
                } else if (n == Math.abs(dividend)) {
                    ans = count + 1;
                    break;
                } else {
                    n += Math.abs(divisor);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        if((dividend<0 && divisor>0) || (dividend>0 && divisor<0))
              ans*=-1;
        return ans;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int dividend=sc.nextInt();
        int divisor = sc.nextInt();
        int ans=quotient(dividend,divisor);
        System.out.println(ans);
```

}

but this code is failing for this test case and I am getting its output as `-2147483648`and the expected output is `2147483648`. I tried using `Math.abs(_)` but it is also not working.

**Inputs:**

**-2147483648
-1**

Why is this happening? Please explain.

Comment: Long Integer maximum value in Java is `2147483648`, and its minimum is negative `2147483648`. I don't know why this problem is happening, but maybe this can help.

Comment: @Yan, not true.

Comment: @fluffy, check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004944/max-value-of-integer

Comment: @Yan, `int`/`java.lang.Integer` max value is exactly `+2_147_483_647`, and not `+2147483648` which cannot be hold in a 32-bit int at all.

Comment: @fluffy, sorry, it was just a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is an Integer overflow. As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004944/max-value-of-integer), the maximum value of Long Integer is `2147483647`, and there is no such `int` value as `2147483648`, so it goes to `-2147483648` as the next integer when adding `1`. You can try the `long` type for solving this problem, its maximum is `9223372036854775807` in Java (that's a lot).